# Help with test coverage

Tags: trigger, unit-test

I was wondering if someone would be able to help me create a test class for the following code as I am programmatically challenged :) any help would be greatly appreciated!!! Thanks in advance!!!

```
trigger RFS_OpportunityValidations on Opportunity(before update){

    Set<Id> oppsToBeChecked = new Set<Id>();
    Profile adminId = [SELECT Id from Profile where Name='System Administrator' LIMIT 1];

    for(Opportunity o : trigger.new){
        if(o.Probability >= 70 && UserInfo.getProfileId() != adminId.Id){
            oppsToBeChecked.add(o.Id);
        }
    }
    // check their products in greater detail
    if(!oppsToBeChecked.isEmpty()) { // maybe we don't need to run the query at all?   
        for(OpportunityLineItem oli : [SELECT OpportunityId 
        FROM OpportunityLineItem 
        WHERE OpportunityId IN :oppsToBeChecked
            AND PriceBookEntry.Product2.RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Prospect_Product' 
            AND PriceBookEntry.Product2.Approved__c = false]){

            trigger.newMap.get(oli.OpportunityId).addError('Opportunities with => 70% must not include Prospect Products. Please replace these with real SAP Products to continue.');
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here is my test case so far but am getting the following error and can't go any further:

Pass/Fail: Fail

Error Message: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, This price definition already exists in this price book: []

Stack Trace: Class.RFS_OpptValTriggerTest.myUnitTest: line 38, column 1

```
@isTest(seeAllData=true)
private class RFS_OpptValTriggerTest {

    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {       

//Data Prep
//Create Account, Opportunity, Product, etc.
        Account acct1 = new Account(name='test Account One1');
        insert acct1;
//Create Opportunity on Account
        Opportunity Oppty1 = new Opportunity(name='test Oppty One1');
        Oppty1.StageName = 'Selected';
        Oppty1.CloseDate = Date.today() + 30;
        insert Oppty1;         

// Create Products 
         Product2 testprod1 = new Product2 (name='test product one1');
         testprod1.productcode = 'test pd code1one';
         testprod1.Approved__c = false;
         testprod1.CanUseRevenueSchedule = True;
         insert testprod1;
         Product2 testprod2 = new Product2 (name='test product two2');
         testprod2.productcode = 'test pd code2two';
         testprod2.Approved__c = True;
         testprod2.CanUseRevenueSchedule = True;
         insert testprod2;
// Get Pricebook
         Pricebook2 testpb = [select id from Pricebook2 where IsStandard = true];
         testpb.IsActive=true;
         update testpb;   
// Add to pricebook
        PriceBookEntry pbe1 = new PricebookEntry();
        pbe1.UnitPrice = 100;
        pbe1.Product2Id = testprod1.Id;
        pbe1.Pricebook2Id = testpb.id;
        pbe1.IsActive = true;
        pbe1.useStandardPrice = false;
        insert pbe1;
        PriceBookEntry pbe2 = new PricebookEntry();
        pbe2.UnitPrice = 200;
        pbe2.Product2Id = testprod2.Id; 
        pbe2.Pricebook2Id = testpb.id;
        pbe2.IsActive = true;
        pbe2.useStandardPrice = false;
        insert pbe2;

Test.startTest();

Oppty1.StageName='Selected';
update Oppty1;
System.assertNotEquals('Prospecting', Oppty1.StageName); ***not sure if this part is even correct

Test.stopTest();
}
}
```

Comment: What have you written so far?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I haven't written anything yet. I just started some Google searches to get me started in the meantime. I have VERY limited coding experience so most of what I write will be trial and error.

Comment: Take a look at [An Introduction to Apex Code Test Methods](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods), have a go, then come back with specific questions if you get stuck. Alternatively, you could ask over at the [Force.com Discussion Boards](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/bd-p/apex).  The discussion boards work better for these kind of open-ended questions.

Comment: I have edited my original post to include some test code I found and modified.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pricebooks (and Products for that matter) seem to be copied over to sandboxes, even the developer ones. So I don't think you need to insert these PricebookEntry records? Also [this info](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_data_access.htm) seems to be a bit discouraging:

> Inserting a pricebook entry for a product isn’t feasible from a test
> since the standard pricebook isn’t accessible and can’t be created in
> a running test. Also, inserting a pricebook entry for a custom
> pricebook isn’t supported since this requires defining a standard
> pricebook. For such situations, annotate your test method with
> IsTest(SeeAllData=true) so that your test can access organization
> data.

So I'd say apply the annotation (ok, you already have it) and check what does this return:
`System.debug([select id from Pricebook2 where IsStandard = true]);`

if it looks promising (returns some ids) - query `SELECT Id, Pricebook2Id, Pricebook2.Name, Product2Id, Product2.Name FROM PricebookEntry` and use these while adding OpportunityLineItems?

Comment: I will try playing with this a little. If I query the DB for an Id in Pricebook2 I get one record. I think I am still missing some lines in my code to actually add the products to the opportunity. Little by little I will figure this out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You probably do have only 1 Pricebook. The point is that it might contain many items (entries) that are a link between pricebook and product. Is http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_products.htm of any help? Run this query, apologies for the typo in the answer `SELECT Id, Pricebook2Id, Pricebook2.Name, Product2Id, Product2.Name FROM PricebookEntry`

Comment: Thanks will try that as well... need to figure out the code logic.

Answer (score 1):

You want to test each probable code branch. It looks like you want to take the following into consideration:

1. The test code must run as a non-administrator. You should either create a user with a different profile or query for one to use in your testing. Then use [System.runAs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm) to run the tests as the user.
2. Your opportunity probability must be greater than 70%. When you create your test opportunity, you should make sure you give it a probability.
3. Your opportunity can't have a prospect on it. You should try opps with and without these types of product.

Since you are adding an error to the opportunity, your test code needs a try...catch around your `update Oppty1` to catch the error and confirm it is the one you are expecting to get back.

Comment: And as a side note on exception testing -- have a failing assert at the end of any `try` block that is supposed to fail.  You'll catch test cases where there wasn't an exception when there should have been one (since your `catch` block won't run).  I've seen this happen in multiple test methods -- you're so focused on making sure the correct exception is generated that you forget to test whether there was even an exception.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot! I will have to see if I can find similar examples for all of the above.